# How to get certain number of alphabets from a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a 26-digit list. I want to print out a list of alphabets according to the numbers. For example, I have a list(consisting of 26-numbers from input):

```
[0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

I did like the output to be like this:

```
[e,e,l,s]
```

'e' is on the output 2-times because on the 4-th index it is the 'e' according to the English alphabet formation and the digit on the 4-th index is 2. It's the same for 'l' since it is on the  11-th index and it's digit is 1. The same is for s. The other letters doesn't appear because it's digits are zero.

For example, I give another 26-digit input. Like this:

```
[1,2,2,3,4,0,3,4,4,1,3,1,4,4,1,0,0,0,0,0,4,2,3,2,2,1]
```

The output should be:

```
[a,b,b,c,c,d,d,d,e,e,e,e,g,g,g,h,h,h,h,i,i,i,i,j,k,k,k,l,m,m,m,m,n,n,n,n,o,u,u,u,u,v,v,w,w,w,x,x,y,y,z]
```

Is, there any possible to do this in Python 3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `chr(97 + item_index)` to get the respective items and then multiply by the item itself:

```
In [40]: [j * chr(97 + i) for i, j in enumerate(lst) if j]
Out[40]: ['ee', 'l', 's']
```

If you want them separate you can utilize `itertools` module:

```
In [44]: from itertools import repeat, chain

In [45]: list(chain.from_iterable(repeat(chr(97 + i), j) for i, j in enumerate(lst) if j))
Out[45]: ['e', 'e', 'l', 's']
```

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, it is definitely possible in Python 3.**

Firstly, define an example list (as you did) of numbers and an empty list to store the alphabetical results.

The actual logic to link with the index is using **chr(97 + index)**, **ord("a") = 97** therefore, the reverse is **chr(97) = a**. First index is 0 so 97 remains as it is and as it iterates the count increases and your alphabets too.

Next, a nested for-loop to iterate over the list of numbers and then another for-loop to append the same alphabet multiple times according to the number list.

We could do this -> **result.append(chr(97 + i) * my_list[i])** in the first loop itself but it wouldn't yield every alphabet separately [a,b,b,c,c,d,d,d...] rather it would look like [a,bb,cc,ddd...].

```
    my_list = [1,2,2,3,4,0,3,4,4,1,3,1,4,4,1,0,0,0,0,0,4,2,3,2,2,1]
    result = []

    for i in range(len(my_list)):
        if my_list[i] > 0:
            for j in range(my_list[i]):
                result.append(chr(97 + i))
        else:
            pass

    print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the wonderful answer by @Kasramvd

```
import string


n = [0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

res = [i * c for i, c in zip(n, string.ascii_lowercase) if i]
print(res)  # -> ['ee', 'l', 's']
```

Your second example produces:

```
 ['a', 'bb', 'cc', 'ddd', 'eeee', 'ggg', 'hhhh', 'iiii', 'j', 'kkk', 'l', 'mmmm', 'nnnn', 'o', 'uuuu', 'vv', 'www', 'xx', 'yy', 'z']
```

---

Splitting the strings (`'bb'` to `'b', 'b'`) can be done with the standard schema:

```
[x for y in something for x in y]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a slightly different approach, which gives the characters individually as in your example:

```
import string

a = [0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

alphabet_lookup = np.repeat(np.arange(len(a)), a)
letter_lookup = np.array(list(string.ascii_lowercase))

res = letter_lookup[alphabet_lookup]
print(res)
```

To get

```
['e' 'e' 'l' 's']
```